# Liking system, how do I fix it?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have the following script for showing posts and liking them, but if I like  one post it likes all the posts on the page, I can't think of another way to do it, can anyone give me some advice?

```html
<?php 
if ($sort == 1){
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4 ");
}
elseif($sort == 2)
{
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR ORDER BY likes DESC");
}
elseif($sort == 3)
{
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY likes DESC");
}

 
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
          <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image1'] ?>" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title"><?php print title; ?></h2>
              <p class="card-text"><?php print text; ?></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
 
              Posted on <?php print $row['date'] ?> by
              <a href="#"><?php print $row['author']; ?> </a>
<?php
$id=$row['id'];      
if($_POST['like']) {
$update = "UPDATE posts set `likes` = `likes`+1 where `id` ='$id'";
if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
} 
} ?> 
 <form action="" method="POST">
<button type = "submit" value = "like" name='like'style="font-size:24px"><?php echo $row['likes']; ?><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</form>

    </div>
          </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Move the `update` outside of the `while` loop. You also are open to SQL injections. Parameterize

Comment: Thanks, i solved it, can you please explain more with sql injection fix?

Comment: use prepared statements in php. here is w3school link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: mode on sql injection here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: I read trough some of that, but i fail to see where should i use something like that, can you give me a more detailed hint, please? Thanks! Do i need it if the user doesn`t input anything? Are you talking about the liking sistem or the whole script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop contains the update query so your code should be change like this.
in order to get the id to like you just need to use a hidden field to post that id like in this code

```
<?php

if($_POST['like']) {
$id=$POST['id'];
$update = "UPDATE posts set `likes` = `likes`+1 where `id` ='$id'";
if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
} 
} ?> 

<?php 
if ($sort == 1){
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4 ");
}
elseif($sort == 2)
{
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR ORDER BY likes DESC");
}
elseif($sort == 3)
{
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY likes DESC");
}


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
          <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image1'] ?>" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title"><?php print title; ?></h2>
              <p class="card-text"><?php print text; ?></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer text-muted">

              Posted on <?php print $row['date'] ?> by
              <a href="#"><?php print $row['author']; ?> </a>

 <form action="" method="POST">
 <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<button type = "submit" value = "like" name='like'style="font-size:24px"><?php echo $row['likes']; ?><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</form>

    </div>
          </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```